# getting the correct image url

Tags: php

i have this image link below:

```
http://ws.assoc-amazon.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=B008EYEYBA&Format=_SL110_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=US&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=mytwitterpage-20
```

but if you click it and view it in a browser, the actual url of the image file is this:

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/418lsVTc0aL._SL110_.jpg
```

any idea how I can parse the image link above to get the actual jpg file using php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

function get_url($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_exec($ch);

    if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
        $url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $url;
}

echo get_url("http://ws.assoc-amazon.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=B008EYEYBA&Format=_SL110_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=US&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=mytwitterpage-20");
```

[Source](http://wireshock.com/find-redirected-url-using-php-with-this-simple-function/)

Comment: awesome, easy and simple to understand, great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`get_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php), and get the `Location:` header:

```
$headers = get_headers($url);
echo $headers['Location'];
```

Note:

This is the most basic version and it will work as long as there is only 1 redirect. If you run into more complex issues, use @aykut's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this :

```
header('Content-type:image/png');
$file=file_get_contents($url);
```